# Is there a way to do a dry run with serverless CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I want to test the resolution of variables inside my serverless.yaml file, e.g. some come from command line, some from a file and others from s3.

e.g.

```
environment
  whitelist: ${file(config/forwardproxy.sit.yaml):Common.defaultWhitelist}
```

I want to do a deploy with a dry run. The --nodeploy option only seems to be available with azure provider.

Is there a way to do this with the AWS provider?

Comment: —noDeploy works with AWS as a provider also

Comment: @hephalump - not on 1.47. I tried it and it updated my stack. What version are you on?

Comment: Not sure which version we’re using it in; we are using it, but you’re right it may be an old version. You can also try ‘serverless package’ which will package it up to the .serverless directory pre-deployment. https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/package/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use `serverless package` for the purpose of testing variable resolution, syntax checking, plugin configuration, etc. If you have no use for the zip it creates, you can just trash it afterwards.

Comment: It also create the Cloudformation .json files as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use plugin [serverless-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline) to run lambdas (if that's what you are trying to do).

**Usage:** `$ serverless offline`

Comment: Thanks, but as cool as that plugin is, it's not what I'm looking to do :)